# HTTP JVM: boom : Message in domino server log

Tags: xpages

I can see "HTTP JVM: boom" message in server log coming sometimes, 
what does it mean? 
Can you please explain if something going wrong.
Server sometimes crashes also, is it any clue to that. We have a big xpage application running on server which is being accessed by lot of people always and posting big images files etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sysout from developer unit testing code included as a consequence of a concurrent code merge conflict in an early 8.5.3 codestream.  It has since been removed from the codestream.  It was part of debugging fail-safe try/catch code introduced when making the CD/MIME code more robust but not something you should be alarmed about. It is highly unlikely to be related to the crash you sometimes experience - you should report this crash via the regular IBM support channel.

Comment: Interesting, Tony :-) Subhasish, what version of Domino are you running?

Comment: Thanks Tony for your prompt reply. Domino server is 8.5.3 FP4, We have been facing issue similar to this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO69254; Is there is any solution for the same?

Comment: Thank god he just used 'boom' and not something offensive ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a result of a System.out.println in your Java code that is running somewhere.

Comment: Agree. Search your nsf for "boom"